# How to find a specific word inside QUERY_STRING

Tags: php

I need to search a string for a specific word
I try different way but I have always an error
Blog&Content is th element than I want to find fo example

> Warning: strpbrk() expects parameter 2 to be string,

```
$string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

var_dump($string);
if (strpbrk($string, $page) !== false) {
  var_dump('true');
}
```

sorry the elements

```
var_dump($string) = string(31) "Blog&Content&blog_content_id=25" 
var_dump($page) array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "Blog&Content" [1]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: What is `$page`? Where is it defined?

Comment: strpbrk() only searches for specified characters, not whole words: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php Maybe strpos() will work better for you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: see below new elements

Comment: `$page` is an array, not a string.

Comment: $page is an array, not a string, so try: if(strpos($string, $page[0]))

Answer (score 0):

Your *specific word* is at `0` position of the `$page` array.
 Use the following:

```
$string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

var_dump($string);
if (strpos($string, $page[0]) !== false) {
  var_dump('true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others recommended using `strpos()` to check for substring existence, but that would not be a trustworthy method to use outside of the isolation of your sample.  The target string could just as easily exist as a value rather than a key.

As a matter of better practice, use `parse_str()` on `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` and call `isset()` as needed in your condition statement.

Code:  (assuming `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]="Blog&Content&blog_content_id=25"`):

```
parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"],$qs);
// $qs=array('Blog'=>'','Content'=>'','blog_content_id'=>'25');
if(isset($qs['Blog']) && isset($qs['Content'])){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Make it easy on yourself and enjoy all of the benefits of converting the query string into an array.

Comment: @Amy if this answer satisfies, please award it the green tick.  If not, please leave me a comment to explain what isn't quite right for you and I'll try to fix it up.